# Preformatting string Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a list such as this that is defined at the start of my code:

```
string = "You lost {x} passengers after your failed expedition"
```

I want to keep the string defined at the start of the code, but be able to input random values into it later on such as this:

```
print(string(50)) # "You lost 50 passengers after your failed expedition"
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: google `python concatenate strings`

Comment: Google `python format strings`

Comment: @jsotola Only things I found were using % which is depracticated, is .format still valid in python 3.9?

Comment: Yes, it is still valid in Python 3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = "You lost {} passengers after your failed expedition"

print(string.format(50))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.format()`.

Like this:

```
string = "You lost {} passengers after your failed expedition"
string = string.format('50')
```